# Basic 3D geometry problem

Tags: geometry, 3d

*Here's 1 lb of butter


What is the area of the wrapper around it?*
[image]

My answer :

4(11,5 * 6,3) = 289,80cm^2
2(6,3 * 6,3) = 79,38cm^2

289,80 + 79,38 = 369,18cm^2

A = 369,18cm^2

Teacher's answer :

A = L * l
A = 17,8 * 25,2
A = 448,56 cm^2

---

Why am i wrong?
I'm pretty sure i've done everything right, beside the fact i created my own formula instead of using the illogical one  *A = 2(Lh + lh + Ll)*

Comment: I recommend using $h, l, w$ and not 2 different l's.

Comment: It looks like you and your teacher are working on different problems, from what you've put here. Your teacher has calculated $(l+w)(l+w+h)$, and I don't know what that's all about.

Comment: @qwr I can't, it's the actual formula used in public schools where i live.

Comment: The teacher answer is reasonable, sort of. We can wrap the butter using a rectangular sheet of wrapping of that size. Need to fold it over the two small ends of the butter.

Comment: You certainly have computed correctly the *surface area* of the butter. But if you take actual supermarket butter, and carefully unwrap it, you may find that it is wrapped like a present. Probably even more wrapping will be used, so as to give some overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you're approach successfully calculates the *surface area* of the pound of butter.

If that is/was the objective, you've achieved it.

My hunch is that in order to construct a *wrapper* for the pound of butter, you need to find the area of a rectangular sheet of wrapping paper to accommodate both the surface area of the butter, *and* enough to fold it over the smaller opposing ends.

Answer (score 0):

What you calculated was just the area of the wrapper on just one side of the pound of butter.  To find the area of the whole wrapper, we need to find the sum of the areas of all the sides or what we call the **surface area**.

Since a pound of butter is typically in the shape of a rectangular prism, we can use the following formula to find the surface area:

$SA=2LW+2LH+2WH$

$L=11.5$ cm

$W=6.3$ cm

$H=6.3$ cm

In the end, we should get that the wrapper around a pound of butter has an area of 370.38 cm^2.